# XCode UITextField

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

Inside the **.h**:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {

   IBOutlet UITextField *phonenum;
   IBOutlet UITextField *email;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *phonenum;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *email;

-(IBAction) btnClicked: (id) sender;
@end
```

Inside the **.m**:

```
-(IBAction) btnClicked: (id) sender{


NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSLog(@"str=%@",str);  //this contains valid value
email.text=str;  /// does not set the value
[[self email] setText: str];  // does not set the value
}
```

What am i doing wrong where it does not set the UITextField value using the variable str that is NSString?  Is this some kind of Inteface Builder setting?  I have delegate link to file owner.

Comment: Did you link you outlets in Interface Builder ?

Comment: Thank you TDeBailleul.  I was missing the linking of Reference Outlet for email (UITextField) and phone (UITextField).

Comment: Ok, I added an answer, so you can accept it and set your question to 'solved'

Answer (score 2):

It seems that str is nil, so nothing happens. And your 2 last lines do the same thing.
You should write

`NSString *str = email.text;`

And then do something with str, like

`user.email  = str;`

or directly

`user.email = email.text`

if you want to update a user email with the text in your UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to connect your outlets with the interface in Interface Builder

If you don't know how to do that, please see :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CreatingOutlet.html